# Convert grammar to Greibach form

Tags: formal-grammars, pushdown-automata, normal-forms

The grammar is
 $S \rightarrow AA|a$
$A \rightarrow SA|ab$
The actual question is to find an NPDA accepting the language generated by this grammar but for that i firstly need to convert it into Greibach form. I tried to substitute one rule in another but it didn't help. Any hints would be very helpful.

Comment: Use the canonical algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

A context-free grammar can be simulated by a PDA with a single state (assuming acceptance by empty stack, for final state acceptance we need two states). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) suggests two solutions.

**Any** context-free grammar can be simulated using a expand-match method. The PDA nondeterministically kind of generates a right-most derivation, and whenever a terminal is generated, it should be read from the tape.

- expand. For production $A\to\alpha$ have instruction $(1,\varepsilon,1,A,\alpha)$
- match. For any terminal $a$ have instruction $(1,a,1,a,\varepsilon)$

The other (more direct) method is given for grammars in Greibach normal form, but will also work for Chomsky normal form. For any production $A\to a\alpha$, where $a$ is terminal **or** $\epsilon$, and $\alpha$ is a nonterminal string introduce $(1,a,1,A,\alpha)$.

Your example can of course be handled with the first method. For the second one, only the production $A\to ab$ cannot be directly dealt with. Either split that production, or use extra states in the PDA.